# GigE camera output is not what is expected. Showing different images in eBus viewer and camera software

Tags: opencv, interpolation, colorfilter, gige-sdk

Below is the image we are getting from our ethernet camera(AOS promon 501).It is saying the format is bayergb8 but it is quite different and blurry with some lines on it but when we are looking at the feed in the software provided by them it is clear and nice we tried to take the raw image and use interpolation and everything to convert it into rgb image but everything we did, we got some awkward output.We are attaching the images from the software and Pleora eBus viewer.
[Images attached here](https://imgur.com/gallery/F9sB1e4)

I was trying to interpolate it further but apparently the image has already been interpolated. I am using Harvesters library to get the images and want to interface the camera using code for downstream tasks.